# Help with joining parts of a model using boolean modifier

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to merge together two parts (the ones in the images) of a model using a boolean (union) modifier, but I get an error saying "Unable to execute boolean modifier". I browsed around a little but couldn't really find an answer which worked in my case, so I'm wondering how I can get the boolean modifier to work ~

[image][image]

Comment: I'm guessing your model is non manifold. 
Also, edges directly placed on other edges will cause the boolean to fail in certain cases. you should make sure that this isn't causing any problems.
Another thing: did you check if the normals are facing outwards?

Comment: Are you able to post a .blend?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) as mentioned in comments. After making mesh manifold Boolean modifier worked properly.